# In Fabric Answers, how long will events be stored when offline?

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I am working on a mobile App that can be disconnected from the network for long periods of time, yet we still want to be able to collect statistics and include the results even if they reporting is significantly delayed.  I am looking at different analytics including [Fabric's Answers](https://answers.io) by Twitter.

In the article [Handling Five Billion Sessions A Day In Real Time](http://answers.io/blog/handling-five-billion-sessions-a-day-in-real-time), it says:

> To reduce impact on the device, we send analytics events in batches
>   and compress them before sending. To ensure that valuable data always
>   gets to our servers, devices retry failed data transfers after a
>   randomized back-off and up to a disk size limit on the device. To get
>   events over to the servers as soon as possible, there are several
>   triggers that cause the device to attempt a transfer: a time trigger
>   that fires every few minutes when the app is foregrounded, a number of
>   events trigger and an app going into background trigger.

If the device is disconnected from the network for a long period of time (days), how long will events be saved before being sent?

What is the "disk size limit"?

Will events be ignored by the server if they are too stale (e.g. Google's [Firebase will ignore events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37992145/35577) that are older than 72 hours)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

We don't have any time limitation for when events will be ignored.

We do have a disk limit as you mentioned where we buffer events and will remove them in a FIFO approach if the limit is hit. When this will be hit does vary depending on the number of events being recorded per app session. If you're recording hundreds of events per app session, then you would hit the limit faster then if you're recording a few events per app session.

One key thing to note is that the events will be counted on the day that they are received on our servers.