# How to import offline conversion data into Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, import, google-analytics, offline, firebase-analytics

I am looking for ways to import offline conversions into Firebase Analytics. My app is a shopping aggregator to discover deals and coupons from online retailers. User is then redirected to merchant app or website for completing the transaction ( external to my app/website). I get offline reports from retailors everyday day about confirmed transactions.

How can i import this offline transaction data into Firebase analytics, such that i can see funnels and segmentation for these transacting users in analytics UI?

Google Analytics supports multiple ways of importing offline conversions:
Hitbuilder: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/
Measurement Protocol: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

What is the counterpart of these tools in Firebase Analytics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am running into the same issue.. Would be interesting to know how to achieve such a behaviour.

Answer (score -4):

If the app is offline, all the events or events are stored locally and will be uploaded when the app is online and has a connectivity. Events which arrive for more than 72 hours late will be ignored by the Firebase server.

See original answer by Steve Ganem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37992145/6523173).