# What happen in google analytic SDK if firebase platform is not reachable or giving error responses

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

What will happen in google analytic SDK if firebase platform is not reachable or giving error responses.

Comment: can you add some more information on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can test it on an emulator by rerouting the requests to the firebase endpoint to localhost. Or just disabling the internet.

The default behavior is to cache sent events to then send them when the server is available. Here's a good answer, going more in-depth: [Does Firebase Analytics Work Offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984355/does-firebase-analytics-work-offline)